# Julia periodic function

Tags: function, julia

I'm trying to create a periodic function but I get:

`MethodError: no method matching`

```
##   Defining the drift function
function drift_a(x)
    if  0<=x<2/3
        return 2/7-x-2/7*(1-3*x)*sqrt(abs(1-3*x))
    end
    if  2/3<=x<=1
        return -2/7+2/7*x
    end
end

function drift_b(x)
    return 12*(drift_a(x-floor(x))+0.05)
end

print(drift_b(0.5))
print(drift_b(10.5-floor(10.5)))
print(drift_b(10.5))
```

I'm new to Julia so I don't understand why it throws an error. I have tried creating a placeholder variable `y = x-floor(x)` and using the function on `y` instead, but it gives the same error.

Comment: did you want `function drift_a(x)` `y` is never referred to in `drift_a`

Comment: that was a typo from trying to use y = x-floor(x), it has been corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed it using mod instead

```
function drift_b(x)
    return 12*(drift_a(mod(x,1))+0.05)
end
```